# SSO - black screen - issue

Tags: single-sign-on

We are facing strange issue for SSO login. user landing on blank screen(blue color).

1. This is not happening every time.
2. if users landing on blue screen, we are deactivating and activating back in IDp then they are able to login.
3. This is randomly happening for some users, no browser and version dependent (troubleshooted with different browser and version - not able to replicate)
4. Not able to replicate in lower sandbox. its happening in production

Answer (score 0):

Have you already reviewed this article? The issue you're facing sounds similar.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390864&type=1

"Resolution

This can be caused by the setting "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated'' under the Session Setting. Enabling this can cause the type of content/session - content/recession loops seen in the HAR file gathered leading to too many redirect errors when the customer's login IP does not match the remote address IP in the request.

To resolve the issue, you will need to uncheck the Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated checkbox from Session Setting.

Please note that this setting does not affect logging into mobile. If you need a quick workaround, the user may log in via a mobile device."

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing article @Ben Scott. Let me check with by disabling

Comment: setting already disabled in production and lower sandbox.